# Can't fix Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView for Android 6.0 below

Tags: android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

Whenever I run my application on Android 6.0 below, the app will crash and show the error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #81: Binary XML file line #81: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView. It works fine on Android 7.0 and up.

I have tried the possible solutions that I found in stack overflow but nothing is working.

My MainActivity.xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="Self Care"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMain2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="a SELF assessment test that will provide access to mental health CARE"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Take the assessment test."
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnQuiz"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="Start"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

My MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = getSupportActionBar();
    toolbar.setTitle("");

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    btnQuiz = findViewById(R.id.btnQuiz);

    btnQuiz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Assessment.class));

        }
    });

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);


}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.quiz:
                return true;
            case R.id.history:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HistoryActivity.class));
                return true;
            case R.id.about:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoActivity.class));
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.main: {
            break;
        }

        case R.id.logoutMenu: {
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
            finish();
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.trixia.selfcare"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Crash log

```
01-07 21:00:01.853 8523-8523/com.example.trixia.selfcare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.trixia.selfcare, PID: 8523
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.trixia.selfcare/com.example.trixia.selfcare.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #81: Binary XML file line #81: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #81: Binary XML file line #81: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.trixia.selfcare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #81: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.trixia.selfcare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.trixia.selfcare.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080084
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
    at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:505)
    at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationItemView.initialize(BottomNavigationItemView.java:105)
    at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView.buildMenuView(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:523)
    at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationPresenter.updateMenuView(BottomNavigationPresenter.java:62)
    at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.inflateMenu(BottomNavigationView.java:254)
    at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:187)
    at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:114)
```

What I want is to inflate the BottomNavigationView without crashing the app on Android 6.0 and below.

Comment: post your build.gradle for app module.

Answer (score -1):

You are using older design support dependency. Try updating your dependency with latest available. Replace your dependency with below one.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

From the error Log it looks like some image that you have used are unsupported or corrupt, If you are using drawables make sure you have configured them correctly. If image is available for all drawbles.

Comment: don't use `+` in versions

Comment: This doesn't work. The app still crashes and shows the same error @Karan Mer

Comment: did you perform build and clean? also update your question and post the crash log

Comment: your error is due to `ResourcesNotFoundException` there might be some image that can be corrupt or unsupported, If you are using vector drawables make sure you are using them correctly.

Comment: I fixed it by copying the drawable-v24 to the drawable folder. I forgot to check that. Thank you